# Porting software to Windows, where do I put /usr/share stuff?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I'm writing a program called Bezitopo on Linux and have to port it to Windows. It's a CMake project in C++ using the basic Qt libraries (Core Widgets Gui LinguistTools) and has some files (a list of projections, and some translation files) that have to be installed where the program can find them. On Linux, they go in ~/share/ when I'm developing it and will go in /usr/share once it's packaged. On Windows I know that the libraries go in the same directory as the executable, but where do the projections and translations go?

```
install(TARGETS bezitopo convertgeoid viewtin DESTINATION bin)
install(TARGETS bezilib0 bezilib1 DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h DESTINATION include/bezitopo)
install(FILES ${qm_files} projections.txt transmer.dat DESTINATION share/bezitopo)
install(FILES ${header_files} DESTINATION include/bezitopo)
install(FILES bezitopo.h DESTINATION include)
```

Installing the header files of the Bezitopo library is probably not important on Windows, but installing projections.txt, transmer.dat, and the translation files is required.

I have made the program run in Windows in the build directory, but I have not tried to install it on Windows yet. I'm away on a visit and brought only my Linux laptop; my Windows laptop is at home, and I'll return home in a week.

I use MinGW to build it and type in the bash shell (which came with Git).

Comment: ***but where do the projections and translations go?*** Probably some folder near the executable unless the data needs to be changed. An application can read from files in `C:\Program Files\myAppName\somefolder` but not write files there without elevation.

Comment: Don't bother with shared components on Windows (nobody does). Just bundle all the necessary stuff together with your application and be done with it.

Comment: Search the internet for "Windows DLL hell".

Answer (score 1):

Usually on windows, each application get it's own prefix:

```
C:/Program Files/App1/bin/app1.exe
C:/Program Files/App2/bin/app2.exe
```

In your case, you can simply create a `share` directory in your application prefix:

```
C:/Program Files/bezitopo/share/bezitopo/....
```